# Common area of two squares

Tags: calculus

Two squares are inscribed in a  circle of diameter $\sqrt2$ units.prove that common region of squares is at least 2$(\sqrt2-1)$
This question is in my calculus book but  seems to be algebraic.but frankly speaking i have no idea how to proceed .

Comment: The two squares are congruent, with side 1 (Could you prove it?). The minimal area is when they are rotated by 45 degrees to each other. The proof seems to be straight forward from there..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are infinite squares are possible in circle ,then why we consider square of side 1.and why the minimal  area depends upon angle.could you explain.regards

Comment: Inscribed means that actually the diagonal of the square is ALWAYS a diameter of the circle since the squares are inscribed (draw it!). All infinite squares are congruent. Hope this will clarify the path to solution.

Comment: Sir your  point is cleared to me.what how to prove minimal area .

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way.

[image]

I drew two squares inscribed in the circle centered at the origin with radius $\frac{\sqrt 2}2$. The equation of the line containing the upper side of the red square, which is parallel to the axes, is $y=\frac 12$. The blue square is at an angle of $\alpha$ to the red square. The overlap area is eight times the area of the green triangle. The altitude of the green triangle is $\frac 12$, so to minimize its area we just minimize the length of the triangle's side.

Therefore, use geometry and/or trigonometry to find the length of that side of the triangle, and use trigonometry and/or calculus to find the minimum length of that side, given $0\le\alpha\le \frac{\pi}4$. You will find that the maximum is at $\alpha=0$ and minimum is at $\alpha=\frac{\pi}4$. Calculate the triangle's area at $\alpha=\frac{\pi}4$ and multiply by $8$, and you have your desired minimum overlap area.

I'll give you one more hint: the length of that triangle side is

$$\frac 1{1+\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha}$$

but there are also other ways to express it.

Ask if you need more help, but show some of your own work and state where you are stuck.

Comment: I think you should allow the guy learn how to draw and get results!

Comment: Also, I think you mean minimum at $\pi / 4$

Comment: @Moti: Yes, thank you. I did get that right in most places! Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I really like this picture! Could someone recommend me some software that allows you to make a geometric images like this one?

Comment: @Kusavil: I used Geogebra Classic 5 (at https://www.geogebra.org/) for that and many other drawings. It is free software.